# Can't select/change pricing for IAP (non consumable). Bank, tax info are filled out and it was possible to select before

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

During last week I can't select/change pricing for IAP (non-consumable) for published apps and for new apps too. I can see just next picture:
[image]

Bank, tax info are filled out and it was possible to change pricing before. If somebody had such issue could you please write the solution how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by Apple Support. I just filled out the form like in screenshot below and answered on the questions via email (added screenshots, steps to reproduce etc.):
[image: S]